# Text field to restrict other than (+-0-9%)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a scenario where the text field can accept the following,
`10,+10,-10,+10.00,-10.00,+10.00%,-10.00%`.

I can check the pattern using the RegEx `pattern="[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,4})?%?"`.

But the requirement is to restrict User from typing wrong characters in the field itself rather than throwing the error.

Angular version - 1.6

Comment: Hello, if that is the requirement and you are having problem with that, than you should post code that deals with that specific task. Right now it is just - do all the coding for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would myself just do it easy way and use,

`<input type="number" min="-10" max="10" />`

then just indicate to user that he is inserting percents in this field. works well for mobile users as well.

Otherwise I would probably build some kind of state machine and build json structure for different solutions. then just run it on regexp.

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var stateTree = {
   0 : ['-','+','[0-9]'],
   ... //  basicly declare here possible regexp's per length
   5 : ['[+|-]10\.0']  // could be doing quiet specific one's
  };

  var text = this.value +''+ event.key;
  var array = stateTree[text.length];
  array.map( function(item){
    const match = new RegExp(item, 'g');
    if( text.match(match) ){ this.value = text }
  });

})
```